# Reload or Refresh the MKMapView based on the different preferences or sort types

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, reload

I have an application where the map view has several pins and annotations. These pins should refresh or reload based on the various sort options I have on my view. e.g. The pins represent various buildings, and the filter options are like, Library, Museum, Movie Theater, All Attractions, etc.

I have tried using

```
[MapView reloadInputViews];
```

based on the filtered array after choosing an option. But it simply does not work for me. Any ideas how this would be implemented?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your filter options are totally different entities, you should simply remove all pins on your map and then loop the appropriate array with new filtered datas for adding new pins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I was thinking of something similar, but was curious if there is another way to refresh the maps completely. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 8):

Use `[MKMapView removeAnnotations:]` and `[MKMapView addAnnotation:]` to change the pins that are on the map.

Comment: 1. remove all Annotations using [MKMapView removeAnnotations:] 2. recreate the annotation array based on the new sorting 3. add the new annotation to the map

Comment: Make sure to call these on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

1. remove all Annotations using [MKMapView removeAnnotations:] 2. recreate the annotation array based on the new sorting 3. add the new annotation to the map